LDAP authentication failing in springboot 3
I am trying to connect with an online LDAP using springboot 3.0.8
this is my code
package org.pg.ldap;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class LDAPSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin().and()
                .csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider() {
        DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator authoritiesPopulator =
                new DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator(contextSource(), null);
        authoritiesPopulator.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuthenticator(), authoritiesPopulator);
    }

    @Bean
    public BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator() {
        BindAuthenticator bindAuthenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource());
        bindAuthenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{"uid={0},dc=example,dc=com"});
        return bindAuthenticator;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389");
        contextSource.setBase("dc=example,dc=com");
        contextSource.setUserDn("cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com");
        contextSource.setPassword("password");
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}


It by default shows me a login page upon launching the code , but whenever I try to connect by entering the credentials(username = riemann, password= password), it shows
Failed to bind with any user DNs [uid=riemann,dc=example,dc=com]
LDAP info can be found here : https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/
But when I hit the url using this command
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389 -D "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w password -b "dc=example,dc=com" "(uid=riemann)"
It shows all the info about the user, telling me that LDAP is working fine.
What am I doing wrong here?

I would say your userDnPatterns are off? Shouldn't that only be uid={0} as the other is configured in the binding?
